# Is it possible to use xsl to transform one input document into two output documents

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using XSL to map between two different XSD's. Both contain attachment data as base64.  However it is valid for the input XML two contain multiple attachments in the same XML instance.  Not so for the output XML as it must only contain one attachment per XML instance.  Is it possible to create an XSL that accepts one document as its input and outputs multiple from that if needed?

THX

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using? I ask because xslt 2.0 has `<xsl:result-document method="xml" href="{$filename}">`.

Comment: I am currently using XSLT 1.0 but can use 2.0.  I will give the above a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need XSLT 2.0 (which is now widely available), or you need a 1.0 processor with a vendor extension.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can generate a single output document and then have your calling code break it apart into multiple documents.

Comment: You're assuming XSLT 1.0, which wasn't specified in the question. Besides, this is a good reason for moving forward.